SSRS Shared Data Source Error with Snowflake Key Pair Authentication (ODBC)
I'm encountering an error while creating a shared data source on SSRS using Key Pair Authentication for Snowflake. Currently, we have a working shared data source with Username/Password authentication (ODBC connection type).
This image shows that we are able to connect to Snowflake via ODBC keypair authentication using DSN
When switching to Key Pair Authentication, I receive the following error:

The current action cannot be completed. The user data source credentials do not meet the requirements to run this report or shared dataset. Either the user data source credentials are not stored in the report server database, or the user data source is configured not to require credentials but the unattended execution account is not specified.

This image shows the error that we encountered when trying to do test connection while using the Keypair authentication mechanism
Key points:

Microsoft Report Builder connects successfully to Snowflake using ODBC Key Pair Authentication (embedded connection).
The ODBC DSN is configured following Snowflake's documentation for Key Pair Authentication.

Links for reference:

https://docs.snowflake.com/developer-guide/odbc/odbc-parameters#using-key-pair-authentication
https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-set-up-ODBC-Driver-with-key-pair-authentication-to-connect-to-Snowflake-on-Windows

I expect that the shared data source on the SSRS server should connect successfully to Snowflake using ODBC key pair authentication.
Has anyone encountered this issue with SSRS and Key Pair Authentication? Are there any solutions or workarounds?

Not sure if SSRS supports key pair authentication, but Without Any Credentials would not be the correct choice. You should try Using the Following Credentials with only the userid specified in the DSN  and no password.

Hey, @DaveWelden Thanks for your response. I had already created the DSN by specifying only the userid and privatekey path (password is not part of the DSN) since I am trying out key pair authentication. However, I tried the option that you had suggested, Using the Following Credentials and specified userid and left the password field as blank. The test connection button said successful but the create button is disabled so unable to create a shared data source and confirm whether the shared data source is able to connect to Snowflake via KeyPair authentication.
